# Route to picking up Deep learning

Tags: beginner, deep-learning

I would like to pick up on the topic of deep learning. Should I begin from the topic of AI before working my way into Deep learning?

Comment: Deep Learning is highly related to the theory of neural networks, so it would be good to start learning the basics of artificial neural networks first. See also http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/deep-learning-basics

Comment: This is probably too vague to make a good question. Add some detail about what your background is, what specifically about AI you're wondering if you need to know, etc.

Comment: I am a fresh graduate from a computer science program and have taking classes in algorithm and AI. To my understanding deep learning is a branch under AI, we were taught the basic concept of AI but I was wondering which are should I work on mastering and where should I move on to .

Comment: https://www.coursera.org/course/neuralnets

Comment: @zen I would assume Sean meant for you to edit/expand on the question, not post details as a comment.  I think it would be more helpful to future users that way, if they end up here for the first time through an online search.

Comment: Except of already mentioned great coursera stuff by Geoff Hinton, also this series by Nando de Freitas is worth a look: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLE6Wd9FR--EfW8dtjAuPoTuPcqmOV53Fu

Answer (score 4):

Start with neural nets. They are the basic building blocks of Deep Learning.

[Neural Nets for Newbies video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g-BJSl4zV_g) is a well-explained introduction. [CS-449](http://www.willamette.edu/~gorr/classes/cs449/intro.html) from Willamette University is an free and approachable class in neural networks.

That should lay the foundation for more advanced Deep Learning material. [Deep Learning](http://www-labs.iro.umontreal.ca/~bengioy/dlbook/) by Bengio, Goodfellow, and Courville is a quality book on the subject.